# Colormaps custom using cbfit matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi I am trying to costomize my colormap according to tick values of the of the colorbar. I defined my own colorbar with 5 colors eg 5 colors from blue to red

`cmap_my=[0 0 1;0 1 1;0 1 0; 1 1 0; 1 0 0];`

than i would like that the colour changes for every tick i put. By using cbfit the colors are changing according to the ticks if ticks are evenly distributed in the range of 0:40, but my ticks are

```
h = colorbar;
set(h,'YTick',[5,10,15,22,30,35,40]);
```

and my range is up to 45. In addition to that the colors i have defined dont show anymore when i use cbfit. Is there a possibility to give certain ranges for colors and eg from 5 to 10 dark blue 10 to 15 light blue 15 to 22 green 22 to 30 lightyellow 30 to 35 yellow 35 to 40 orange and over 40 red and than makes clear cuts at the ticks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your problem. Here goes one example. You can work from here for you specific colors.

```
mri=load('mri');
mri=double(mri.D(:,:,1,13));
%making my image within the same range as yours
mri=(mri-min(mri(:)))./(max(mri(:))-min(mri(:)))*45;
figure,imagesc(mri),axis off,axis image,h_bar=colorbar;

%h_map(1) is related with the min(mri), and h_map(end) with max(mri)
h_map=colormap; 
min_mri=0;
max_mri=45;

lim=eps*100;
my_map_int=[0-lim,5-lim,5+lim,10-lim,10+lim,40-lim,40+lim,45+lim];
my_map_color=[0,0,0;0,0,0;0,0,1;0,0,1;0,1,0;0,1,0;1,0,0;1,0,0];

new_map_color(:,1)=interp1(my_map_int,my_map_color(:,1),linspace(min_mri,max_mri,64),'nearest');
new_map_color(:,2)=interp1(my_map_int,my_map_color(:,2),linspace(min_mri,max_mri,64),'nearest');
new_map_color(:,3)=interp1(my_map_int,my_map_color(:,3),linspace(min_mri,max_mri,64),'nearest');

figure,imagesc(mri),axis off,axis image
colormap(new_map_color)
colorbar
```